# Could an organism theoretically produce a metamaterial-like structure?

Tags: evolution, synthetic-biology

I'm curious to know if this is physically feasible because during my reading up on synthetic biology and just general research i realise that life is capable of producing some exquisitely complex materials and biological structures and wondered if they could potentially recreate artficial materials that aren't found in nature well not yet anyway. Could such a structure evolve naturally or would it have to be designed or directed via synthetic biology techniques?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'artficial materials that aren't found in nature'?  Are you talking about chemical production bacteria such as biofuels, or some animal that builds an item such as bone replacements out of coral?

Comment: Hi, im talking about materials that have so far only been produced in labs or manufactured using technology and have not to our knowledge been produced or grown by any living thing. I only wanted to know if life could create such complex structured materials.